# Pass bundle between three activities in Android

Tags: android, bundle, android-intent

I have three activities that I can call A, B and C. I want to pass information between the three like this: A-->B-->C-->A. In A I want to check if there is a bundle passed (the first time, start-up, there won't be one for example).
The data is passed from A-B with a normal bundle. From B-->C I use this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FlashcardView.class);
             i.putExtra("rattning", rattning);
             i.putExtra("noqs", noqs);
             i.putExtra("categoryid", categoryid);
             CreateTestView.this.finish();
             startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

It is received and then sent onwards to A like this:

```
  Intent data = new Intent(FlashcardView.this, MenuView.class);
                       data.putExtra("point", point);
                       data.putExtra("noqs", noqs);
                       setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                       finish();
```

It is received at A like this:

```
 @Override 
   protected void onActivityResult( int req, int resp, Intent data ) {
        super.onActivityResult(req, resp, data);
        // process your received "data" from GameActivity ...
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        noqs = b.getInt("noqs");
        point = b.getInt("point");
        mTvCat.setText("hhhhhh"+point+noqs);
        publishOnFacebook(point,noqs);
    }
```

It seems though like the bundle is lost on the way from C-->A. When I passed it back from C-->B there was no problem. I think this happens cause B is the activity that starts C, and therefore C falls back to B, not A. I made a go-around by calling finish() on B, so C goes back to A instead. BUt in doing this I lose the bundle. Or at least I think so.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a better way of doing this? How can I prevent losing the bundle on a passing between more than two activities? THanks!

Edit:

Edit: Here is the error code on receiving the broadcast:

```
  03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=my_action (has extras) } in com.crystalcodeab.Flashcard.MenuView$1@47681ad0
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:981)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at com.crystalcodeab.Flashcard.MenuView$1.onReceive(MenuView.java:56)
03-07 12:57:59.394: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(803):     at
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem lies in how you finish activity B. When you finish Activity B, the result from B is sent back to A and the Activity is gone. C has no way of knowing it should return its result to A, as it is only aware of Activity B.

My suggestion to you is that you should use a BroadcastReceiver in Activity A. Then in Activity C you can send a Broadcast with the data you wish to be received by A:

In A:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("my.action");
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("my.action")) {
      // Do my stuff
    }
  }
}
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

In C:

```
Intent data = new Intent("my.action");
data.putExtra("point", point);
data.putExtra("noqs", noqs);
sendBroadcast(data);
```

Comment: This sounds right. But I still get a NullPointerException in A, the same as I did before. Is there a way to specify where the broadcast is going? Or is it "in the air" until a receiver is registered?

Comment: Could you post the line from logcat showing the NullPointerException? A broadcast is just sent into the air for anyone with the matching intentfilter to receive. You cannot specify where the broadcast is to be sent other than that.

Comment: I read just now in the Developer docs that broadcast receiver doesn't have to be specified. I might have added the intent filters in an erroneous way, or not specified the receiver in the manifest correctly.

Comment: You do not need to specify a BroadcastReceiver in your manifest. It's perfectly ok to add the receiver in onCreate or some other method in your Activity.

Comment: Now it works! Thanks a lot. If anyone else sees this question: I had to retrieve the intent like this: noqs = intent.getIntExtra("noqs", noqs);

Comment: Hi, I tried in the exact same way. But the receiver isn't getting invoked. am I missing something? My application is having [this Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274110/how-to-validate-input-data-in-a-tab-on-tab-change). I want to pass my data from `tab#1 Activity` to `New Activity #2` using your example. The receiver is under `onCreate` Method of the `New Activity #2` and I am sending the broadcast from a button's `onClickListener` in `onCreate method` of `tab#1 activity`.

Answer (score 0):

When you finish activity B, why are you using a new `Intent` instead of the `getIntent()` method?

Comment: I use a getIntent in B, collect the parameters sent from A. Then I start a new Intent and send parameters to C from B. Here I use the parameters, gather up new ones and want to send these to A.

Comment: see when u r at activity c which is called by B. if you are finishing activity c then onActivityResult of B will be called not of A. so proper way is to first finish activity C and  then on onActivityResult of B call getIntent().getBundle() and then pass it to A and then finish B

Comment: Yes I understand the logic of this. But it is a game and I don't want the user to pass activity B again. Maybe there is a way to do this without it showing visually?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)s instead of activities in your game and manage the state transition within the [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) instead of trying to use the Activity stack.  It seems like it might be a bit easier to manage.